# Dúvida com float

Tags: c, float

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( void ){
float y = 12.0809;
printf("The number %.2f is a float\n");
return 0;
}
```

Sei que `%.2f` é usado para considerar apenas duas casas decimais, mas gostaria de saber para que serve um número inteiro antes do ponto. Por exemplo, `%7.2f` ou `%3.2f`. Se o número que vem depois do ponto é usado para limitar o número de casas decimais, para que serve o número que vem antes do ponto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O número que vem depois do `%` e antes do `.` é o número de caracteres **mínimo** que o número vai na string resultando. Por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Teste 1: '%3.2f' - A\n", 12.0809);
    printf("Teste 2: '%8.2f' - B\n", 12.0809);
    printf("Teste 3: '%08.2f' - C\n", 12.0809);
    return 0;
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Teste 1: '12.08' - A
Teste 2: '   12.08' - B
Teste 3: '00012.08' - C
```

Observe que no teste 2, entre o primeiro `'` e o segundo, há oito caracteres. Obviamente, se a string resultante fosse exceder isso, ela teria tantos caracteres quantos forem necessários (tal como no teste 1).

Colocando um zero logo após o `%`, ao invés de preencher com espaços, o preenchimento ocorre com zeros, tal como no teste 3.

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/tIGHH9)

Referência relevante: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Perfeito! Ótima referência, ótima resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Trata-se apenas de um modo de formatar a saída dos pontos flutuantes. De acordo [com esse tutorial](https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output), o número antes do ponto indica **a quantidade mínima** de números que serão impressos antes do ponto (vírgula em alguns sistemas, mas C segue o padrão ISO, ou seja, é um ponto no final das contas). Enquanto que o número depois da vírgula indica a precisão do número (casas decimais ou números significativos, em alguns casos).

```html
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Float number: %3.2f\n", 3.14159);
}

//output: 3.14
```

De acordo [com esse outro](http://producao.virtual.ufpb.br/books/camyle/introducao-a-computacao-livro/livro/livro.chunked/ch03s07.html):

> *For example, %10.3f will display the float using ten characters with
>   three digits after the decimal point. Notice that the ten characters
>   includes the decimal point, and a - sign if there is one. If the value
>   needs more space than the width specifies then the additional space is
>   used - width specifies the smallest space that will be used to display
>   the value.*

**Tradução livre:**

> Por exemplo, %10.3f mostrará o ponto flutuante com dez caracteres com
>   três dígitos depois da casa decimal. Note que os dez caracteres
>   incluem os três pontos flutuantes e que um "-" será mostrado se não
>   houver qualquer um. Se o valor precisa de mais espaço do que a largura
>   especifica então espaço adicional é usado - **a largura especifica o
>   menor espaço usado para se armazenar o valor**

**Alternativa:**

O `%g` formata o número com quantas casas decimais forem necessárias (precisão), dando preferência ao formato exponencial (notação científica) para números muito pequenos ou muito grandes (1e-5 no lugar de .00001) e removendo zeros desnecessários (176.12 no lugar de 176.1200). Você ainda pode indicar a precisão e a largura mínima como no `%f`.

Answer (score 2):

O que vem depois do `.` é a precisão dos pontos decimais.
O que vem antes do `.` é a largura de digítos que seu programa irá deixar para exibir o valor.

Por exemplo, a instrução: `printf("%9.6f", myFloat)` especifica que a largura dos dígitos de exibição será de 9 espaços. Isso significa que terão 6 espaços depois do ponto, o ponto (isso ja dá 7) por fim, sobram 2 espaços pra exibir antes do ponto.

Veja [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345581/c-printf-a-float-value), e [esse tutorial](https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output).